# error when attempting to push/pull from git repository hosted by assembla

Tags: git, push, dvcs, assembla

I'm getting the following error when attempting to push/pull from my git repository which is being hosted by assembla:

```
E, [2011-07-09T19:00:05.492878 #8781] ERROR -- : git command not recognized
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I'm relatively new to git as I come from the subversion world. I uploaded my public key to assembla and that seems to work as it doesn't appear to be rejecting my key. Is there something common that I might be doing wrong? Is there any other info I could post to help debug what's happening?

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@git.assembla.com:vcweb1.git\n
    fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Comment: Shouldn't you _at least_ post the commands you use, the output of `git remote -v` or (preferrably) the contents of `.git/config`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\n` trailing the remote url seems out of place.

Try removing it